Adjusting Webcam settings while a GStreamer pipeline is runnig
I'm running a WebUI with a live Webcam feed on my Raspberry Pi and I'm trying to adjust the camera settings to fix the overexposure of the camera. When I try to change the settings while the video capture is active I get the following error:
(python3:14781): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:57:14.975: 
Trying to dispose element pipeline28, but it is in PAUSED instead of the NULL state.
You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up.
This problem may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the
application or some element.

[ WARN:0@31.369] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (1356) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline

(python3:14781): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:57:14.975: 
Trying to dispose element videoconvert28, but it is in PLAYING instead of the NULL state.
You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up.
This problem may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the
application or some element.

[ WARN:0@31.369] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (862) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created

(python3:14781): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 14:57:14.975: 
Trying to dispose element appsink28, but it is in READY instead of the NULL state.
You need to explicitly set elements to the NULL state before
dropping the final reference, to allow them to clean up.
This problem may also be caused by a refcounting bug in the
application or some element.

[ WARN:0@31.370] global ./modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (902) open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index

I'm not very familiar with gstreamer itself since I'm just using the OpenCV python library to capture the frames and deliver them to my WebUI.
I tried to adjust the settings using guvcview and then set the resulting default.gpfl file as the default using uvcdynctrl -L default.gpfl before starting the video capture but that returned this error:
[libwebcam] Invalid V4L2 control type encountered: ctrl_id = 0x00980001, name = 'User Controls', type = 6
[libwebcam] Invalid or unsupported V4L2 control encountered: ctrl_id = 0x00980001, name = 'User Controls'
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 user control ID encountered: 0x0098090E (V4L2_CID_USER_BASE + 14)
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 user control ID encountered: 0x0098090F (V4L2_CID_USER_BASE + 15)
[libwebcam] Invalid V4L2 control type encountered: ctrl_id = 0x009F0001, name = 'Image Processing Controls', type = 6
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 control ID encountered: 0x009F0905
[libwebcam] Invalid V4L2 control type encountered: ctrl_id = 0x009D0001, name = 'JPEG Compression Controls', type = 6
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 control ID encountered: 0x009D0903
[libwebcam] Invalid V4L2 control type encountered: ctrl_id = 0x00990001, name = 'Codec Controls', type = 6
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 MPEG control ID encountered: 0x009909CA (V4L2_CID_MPEG_BASE + 202)
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 MPEG control ID encountered: 0x009909CB (V4L2_CID_MPEG_BASE + 203)
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 MPEG control ID encountered: 0x009909CE (V4L2_CID_MPEG_BASE + 206)
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 MPEG control ID encountered: 0x009909CF (V4L2_CID_MPEG_BASE + 207)
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 MPEG control ID encountered: 0x009909D8 (V4L2_CID_MPEG_BASE + 216)
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 MPEG control ID encountered: 0x009909E2 (V4L2_CID_MPEG_BASE + 226)
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 MPEG control ID encountered: 0x009909E5 (V4L2_CID_MPEG_BASE + 229)
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 MPEG control ID encountered: 0x00990A61 (V4L2_CID_MPEG_BASE + 353)
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 MPEG control ID encountered: 0x00990A62 (V4L2_CID_MPEG_BASE + 354)
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 MPEG control ID encountered: 0x00990A66 (V4L2_CID_MPEG_BASE + 358)
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 MPEG control ID encountered: 0x00990A67 (V4L2_CID_MPEG_BASE + 359)
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 MPEG control ID encountered: 0x00990A6B (V4L2_CID_MPEG_BASE + 363)
[libwebcam] Invalid V4L2 control type encountered: ctrl_id = 0x00980001, name = 'User Controls', type = 6
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 user control ID encountered: 0x00980914 (V4L2_CID_USER_BASE + 20)
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 user control ID encountered: 0x00980915 (V4L2_CID_USER_BASE + 21)
[libwebcam] Invalid V4L2 control type encountered: ctrl_id = 0x00980001, name = 'User Controls', type = 6
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 user control ID encountered: 0x0098090E (V4L2_CID_USER_BASE + 14)
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 user control ID encountered: 0x0098090F (V4L2_CID_USER_BASE + 15)
[libwebcam] Invalid V4L2 control type encountered: ctrl_id = 0x009F0001, name = 'Image Processing Controls', type = 6
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 control ID encountered: 0x009F0905
[libwebcam] Invalid V4L2 control type encountered: ctrl_id = 0x00980001, name = 'User Controls', type = 6
[libwebcam] Invalid V4L2 control type encountered: ctrl_id = 0x009A0001, name = 'Camera Controls', type = 6
[libwebcam] Invalid V4L2 control type encountered: ctrl_id = 0x00980001, name = 'User Controls', type = 6
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 user control ID encountered: 0x00980927 (V4L2_CID_USER_BASE + 39)
[libwebcam] Invalid V4L2 control type encountered: ctrl_id = 0x00990001, name = 'Codec Controls', type = 6
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 MPEG control ID encountered: 0x00990A67 (V4L2_CID_MPEG_BASE + 359)
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 MPEG control ID encountered: 0x00990A6B (V4L2_CID_MPEG_BASE + 363)
[libwebcam] Invalid V4L2 control type encountered: ctrl_id = 0x00A40001, name = 'Stateless Codec Controls', type = 6
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 control ID encountered: 0x00A40A95
[libwebcam] Unknown V4L2 control ID encountered: 0x00A40A96

System info:
OS: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) aarch64
Kernel: 6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8

same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78303594/problems-with-videocapture-in-python-using-the-opencv-python-library ?
