Problems with Videocapture in Python and flask
Below is the python code for a simple flask app that displays a webcam feed on a webpage:
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
import cv2

app=Flask(__name__)

cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
def gen():
    while True:

            success,frame=cam.read()
            if not success:
                 continue
            success,frame=cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)
            frame=frame.tobytes()
            yield(b'--frame\r\n'
                    b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
            
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("test.html")

@app.route("/video")
def video():
    return Response(gen(),mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0', port=80)

I implemented my gen() function as the OpenCV documentation and some code examples I found online suggested but when running the app I get the following error:
[ WARN:0@0.088] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:2838 handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module v4l2src0 reported: Device '/dev/video0' is busy
[ WARN:0@0.088] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:1698 open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0@0.088] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:1173 isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
[ WARN:0@0.088] global cap_v4l.cpp:997 open VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video0): can't open camera by index
[ERROR:0@0.109] global obsensor_uvc_stream_channel.cpp:159 getStreamChannelGroup Camera index out of range

I sort of got around this problem by opening and releasing the videocapture for each frame individually like so:

def gen():
    while True:
            cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
            success,frame=cam.read()
            cam.release()
            if not success:
                 continue
            success,frame=cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)
            frame=frame.tobytes()
            yield(b'--frame\r\n'
                    b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')

But that only works with a incredibly low frame rate and it's really frustrating because it should work with first implementation. And no, the camera is not used by any other process. Also the indicator led on my camera turns on while the python code is running and turns off after I stop it.
To resolve this problem I tried reinstalling all the required python libraries and system dependecies like v4l2 and gstreamer. I also tried using different webcams to check if it was a problem with the specific webcam that I was using.

[mre] required. strip all that flask s...tuff out of there.

same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78287920/adjusting-webcam-settings-while-a-gstreamer-pipeline-is-runnig ?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I'd say that's an issue with flask. if you disagree, remove flask from this situation.

I'm able to read and display the frames without using flask. So it indeed seems to be a problem with flask. But what can I do to solve this issue?

AIUI, flask serves HTTP requests. your streaming causes a request to "endure" for as long as the user watches, at least. if there are multiple requests, the second request cannot open the video device because it's already being used. same goes for a request following too quickly. flask may not have cleaned up that worker or thread or whatever mechanism it uses for concurrency. -- you made the same mistake that everyone makes these days. you thought you could just mix web-anything with video processing.

Thanks for your advice. But that didn't seem to be the cause of the problem, but it could evolve into a Problem later on. My issue could be resolved by simply declaring my videocapture within my gen() function instead of declaring it before the function is called. I'm not sure why that is but it works.

The issue could be resolved by simply declaring cam within the gen() function.
